# Does Chrome expose a way for a user to search for a string across all client side variables?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Say I go to some website and they have this code in a `js` file that gets loaded on the client:

```
nacho = {
    "a" : "one",
    "b" : [
        { "d" : "yes", "e" : "no" },
        { "d" : "alpha", "e" : "bravo" },
        { "d" : "hello", "e" : "bye" },
        { "d" : "charlie", "e" : "delta" },
    ],
    "c" : "two"
};

nacho.c = {};
nacho.c["bingo"] = ["one", "two"];
nacho.c["dingo"] = nacho.b[1].d + "dog";
```

Obviously this data would be in Chrome's JavaScript memory, right?

Is there any Chrome way to search everything in the JavaScript memory for any string to see where it might be? For example, say I want to search if the string `alphadog` is anywhere. In the above example it is `nacho.c["dingo"]`.